# How to encrypt and decrypt by chunks in one function calling?

Tags: python, string, encryption, chunks, chunked-encoding

I know that I can encrypt (like on exapmle1) or decrypt by this method .
Bur I would like to ask if I can do both in one calling the function (like example2).
Because if I run this code I have error messages there.
Do you know how to solve in and successfully encrypt and decrypt sentence in one calling?

Thank you

```
import textwrap

def encode(n: int, word: str) -> str:
    
    chunks = textwrap.wrap(word, n)
    reversed_chunks = [chunk[::-1] for chunk in chunks]
    print(' '.join(reversed_chunks))
    



def decode(n: int, word_back: str) -> str: #

    chunks = textwrap.wrap(word_back, n)
    reversed_chunks = [chunk[::-1] for chunk in chunks]
    print(' '.join(reversed_chunks))


print(encode(3, "This sentence could be encrypted ")) #example1

print(decode(3, encode(3, "This sentence could be encrypted and decrypted again"))) #example2
```

Errors:

```
*ihT s s tne cne c e luo d  eb cne pyr det dna ced pyr det aga niTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/george/Desktop/python_codes/sifry2.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(decode(3, encode(3, "This sentence could be encrypted and decrypted again")))
  File "C:/Users/george/Desktop/python_codes/encrypting2.py", line 15, in <module>
    chunks = textwrap.wrap(word_back, n)
  File "C:\Users\george\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\textwrap.py", line 379, in wrap
    return w.wrap(text)
  File "C:\Users\george\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\textwrap.py", line 351, in wrap
    chunks = self._split_chunks(text)
  File "C:\Users\george\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\textwrap.py", line 337, in _split_chunks
    text = self._munge_whitespace(text)
  File "C:\Users\george\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\textwrap.py", line 154, in _munge_whitespace
    text = text.expandtabs(self.tabsize)
builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'
```

Comment: you are calling `decode(... encode(...))`, but `encode()` does not have any `return`

Comment: less subtle hint: replace `print(...)` at the end of both functions with `return ...`

Comment: You need to `return ' '.join(reversed_chunks)` & same in `decrypt`.

Comment: Yes, That is true but now output is: _This sentence coule dncbypeedrndtecaypdedrgatina_ First half is correctly but second is encrypted

Comment: So it looks like the original problem is solved and you have a different problem now. You should create a new question for that instead of piggybacking here, because there can be always one-more-problem-to-solve and it can just keep going.